# Candles, becoming a bas mitzvah on Shabbos

Tags: halacha, shabbat, candle-lighting, bar-bas-bat-mitzvah

If a girl becomes a bas mitzvah exactly on Shabbos, can she fulfill the mitzvah of lighting candles on behalf of another person on that week?

On one hand, the candles are specifically for Shabbos, when she is a bas mitzvah. On the other hand, at the moment she lights them she is not yet a bas mitzvah.

Comment: Or on behalf of herself.   Or a boy for that matter.  But kids that age shouldn't be living alone in any case.

Comment: She does the mitzvah on Erev Shabbos when she is not yet Bas Mitzvah. I don't see the question.

Answer (score 1):

A Kuttan cannot be yotzie anyone that is a Bar Chiuv. She can light for herself before Bat Mitzva, however she cannot light for others. It is no different than any other mitzva.

Comment: Isn't the point to have light in the house? Don't they have light regardless of whether she is a bat hiyyuva?